# Generate even numbers in an int array?

Tags: java

I need to make a 10 element array and the goal is to print out the even numbers from 2 to 20.  I have to do this by adding 2 to the beginning element.  This is what I have so far.  I think I should use a loop as shown but I don't know how to go about adding 2 and printing that out.

```
int[] array = new int[10];

for(int counter=0; counter<array.length; counter++) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want program print even number between 2 & 20

```
for(int i=2;i<=20;i++)
{
   if(i%2 == 0)
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start at 2 and increment by 2 to get the even numbers:

```
int[] array = new int[10]

for(int counter=2; counter <= 20; counter += 2) {
    array[counter/2 - 1] = counter
}
```

or

```
int[] array = new int[10]

for(int i=0; i <= 10; i++) {
    array[i] = i*2 + 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is also an option

```
int i, value;
int nums[] = new int[10];
for (i = 0, value = 2; i < nums.length; value = value + 2, i = i + 1) {
    nums[i] = value;
}
for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(nums[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
int[] array = new int[10];

for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < array.length && j <= 20; j++) {
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
        array[i] = j;
        i++;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8: `int[] array = IntStream.range(1, 11).map(x -> x * 2).toArray();`

Or, to just print: `IntStream.range(1, 11).map(x -> x * 2).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using **do-while**.

you can simply **define a range** of expected even numbers using **minVal** and **maxVal**.

Program will execute and return list of ordered even numbers for given range. Assuming input values are correct even numbers. You can improve to apply validations.

```
public class EvenNumberGenerator {

    static int minVal=2;         //enter valid min value even number
    static int maxVal = 20;      //enter valid max value even number

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList();
        do {
            if(minVal % 2 == 0) {
                evenNumbers.add(minVal);
            }
            minVal++;
        } while (!evenNumbers.contains(maxVal));
        
        System.out.println(evenNumbers);

        // evenNumbers.toArray(); in case you need an array
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

From java-9 you can use `IntStream.iterate` to create `int` array

```
int[] arr= IntStream.iterate(2, i->i<=20, i->i+2).toArray();
```

for `Integer` array you can use `Stream.iterate`

```
Integer[] ary = Stream.iterate(2, i->i<=20, i->i+2).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code as a start, this will work:

```
int[] array = new int[10];

for(int counter=0; counter<array.length; counter++) {
    array[counter] = (counter + 1) * 2;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

The following will also work with [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
int[] array = IntInterval.evensFromTo(2, 20).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.length; i++, j += 2)
    array[i] = j;
```